# Why still get old value of variable after update when import a library

Tags: python, import

Create library `test_module` as following,

```
C:\Software\Python\Lib\site-packages\test_module>dir
 Volume in drive C is OS
 Volume Serial Number is BA4B-6BE1

 Directory of C:\Software\Python\Lib\site-packages\test_module

02/24/2021  01:00 PM    <DIR>          .
02/24/2021  01:00 PM    <DIR>          ..
02/24/2021  12:38 PM                74 test_module.py
02/24/2021  01:00 PM                26 __init__.py
02/24/2021  01:00 PM    <DIR>          __pycache__
               2 File(s)            100 bytes
               3 Dir(s)  43,387,817,984 bytes free
```

```py
# __init__.py
from .test_module import *
```

```py
# test_module.py
VALUE = 10

def set_value(value):
    global VALUE
    VALUE = value
```

```py
# main.py
import test_module as tm

print(tm.VALUE)
tm.set_value(50)
print(tm.VALUE)
```

After run `main.py`

```
10
10
```

My question is why I still get old value of `tm.VALUE`, 10, after `tm.set_value(50)` ?

If just file `test_module.py` and imported, then I will get new value, 50.

```
10
50
```

My target is to find what's wrong when I get the value of `tm.VALUE` after import a library `test_moduel`. It shown the value changed when I called other functions in this library, but wrong value read by the way of `tm.VALUE`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do

```
# __init__.py
from .test_module import *
```

it becomes like

```
# __init__.py
VALUE = 10                         # copied by value

set_value = test_module.set_value  # copied by reference


# test_module.py
VALUE = 10

def set_value(value):
    global VALUE
    VALUE = value
```

So, if you `tm.set_value(50)` from `main.py`, you actucally set `test_module.VALUE` not `__init__.VALUE`.

## Fix 1

Remove `__init__.py` and rename `test_module.py` to `__init__.py`

## Fix 2

Remove the package folder `test_module` and just keep `test_module.py` there instead.

## Fix 3

If you want to directly access to the variable, simply do:

```
# main.py
import test_module as tm

print(tm.test_module.VALUE)
tm.set_value(50)
print(tm.test_module.VALUE)
```

Comment: `main.py` located at any holder, `test_module` located in python library holder and can be import directly. My script import OK, and `from . import test_module as tm` will get `ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package`.

Comment: There's no problem for importing, but why value kept the same after update ?

Comment: @JasonYang I think I got it. So, when you put `test_module.py` next to `main.py`, it works. Right?

Comment: It work when import from a file, fail when import from a library.

Comment: @JasonYang Edited. Please check. :)

Comment: Sorry about it, library cannot be changed ! it's not mine. Question is how can I get right value for such a library.

Comment: @JasonYang The library allows you to modify its global variables...? And what is the **right value**?

Comment: It provide the function to modify global variable. Right value is shown in my question, 10 before update, 50 after updated.

Comment: @JasonYang If the library is reliable, the function should work if you correctly follow the instruction. If it does not work, the library has a bug.

Comment: Everything work fine, I checked the source cod of library, and I want to get that variable directly, then this question.

Comment: I know your way will work, but my question is not how to revise the library, but how to access the variable in my main script.

Comment: @JasonYang If you want to directly access the variable, why don't you do it... I edited. Please check it.

Comment: Fix 3 work for me, thanks for your patient. I will try to find what the meaning.

Comment: @JasonYang `VALUE` is copied by value when `import`ed because it is primitive types. That's all. :)

Comment: So `VALUE` copied, but not for function `set_value`

Comment: @JasonYang Sure. A function is not primitive type. It is copied by reference.